# How best to let users know that the site is responsive, that it should run well on desktops, tablets and mobiles?

Tags: responsive

Most people won't know what "responsive" means.  I thought I might just place a note at the top saying "Optimised for desktops, laptops, tablets and mobiles."

Is their an icon people use?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to indicate this? You don't do such messages for "works on Android and Windows". Chances are people don't even care - they just want it to work on wherever device they're using, so trekking them it works on other things is not really necessary.

Comment: As @illuminaut mentioned below you don't need to announce it. The whole point we have started using this technique is that users don't notice. IT just works and the experience is seamless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole point of a responsive design is that it just works. You shouldn't have to announce the fact that it works as intended on whatever you're using right now - it is apparent by looking at it. "Optimized for" notices are never good practice, but especially not when it is "Optimized for everything".

If your goal is to advertise the fact that you are using good practices, put that somewhere where people care about it, i.e. in the description of the site in your portfolio, but not on the actual site itself.

Comment: To expand on the second paragraph, the best place to do this would be in a blog post announcing and describing the site (re)-design. Those kinds of posts are a great place to show your users how much is going on behind the scenes, without bothering them with it when they have someting important to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you're building a website, it has to be mobile or tablet enabled (responsive). If you don't have a mobile app already, you're missing out on a huge potential audience.

If its not so  you can just put a small popup  as the app starts stating that, the app also works on other devices(although it is not good practice)